# Matlab R2013b (64-bit) cannot integrate git (64-bit)

Tags: windows, git, matlab

I am trying to set up git integration for MATLAB R2013b for my company.

I have a 64-bit matlab version and a 64ibit git version (downloaded from https://git-for-windows.github.io version 2.6.3 portable)

git is correctly found as I can run
! git --version
on the MATLAB shell

However, going to *Preferences->General->Source Control* gives the following message

> You are running a 64-bit version of MATLAB, which does not support
> 32-bit source control systems.
>
> If you have a source control system installed but it is not listed, the likely reason is that it runs in 32-bit compatibility mode. This version of MATLAB is for a 64-bit Windows environment and cannot use a 32-bit source control system. To use source control with this version of MATLAB, you need to get a 64-bit compliant source control system.

[image]

I am sure I have a 64-bit version of git installed. I have been playing a bit with the compatibility mode of the git executable (*Preferences->Compatibility* set to *Windows 7*), but without success

Is there anybody out there who was able to set up git integration for MATLAB R2013b 64-bit? If so, how did you set it up?

Comment: It seems that source control integration requires at least the R2014b version of Matlab : [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history) or [datatool](http://www.datatool.com/downloads/MATLAB_Source_Control_With_Git.pdf)

Comment: I think your are right I am afraid.

Comment: I don't get it. There is a Source Control option in R2013b but it actually only works from R2014b?